# Google AppEngine(Flex) + Cloud SQL Auth Proxy — use different accounts for deploy and access Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm using maven plugin to deploy to AppEngine. I need to be logged in to gloud to be able to deploy services. I need to be logged in to gcloud to be able to use Cloud SQL Auth Proxy also. Now I don't see any way to set deployer account separately to Cloud SQL Auth Proxy account which means I have to use the same account which has broad privileges starting from deployment and ending with 'Cloud SQL Connector/Instance User'. Is it a design flaw? Did I miss something?

Desired state:

1. Manually scaled service in AppEngine Flex (basically a singleton, legacy monolith app)
2. Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance
3. Separate service account for deployment with .json key
4. Separate service account (IAM) for Cloud SQL Auth Proxy with .json key

**UPDATE.**

Temporarily solved by this config:

spring-context.xml

```
<beans profile="appengine">
    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="600000"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="sslmode">disable</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

app.yaml

```
env_variables:
  JAVA_OPTS: >-
    -Ddb.username=postgres -Ddb.password=postgres-password
    -Ddb.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?cloudSqlInstance=project:location:instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory

beta_settings:
  #tcp sockets:
  cloud_sql_instances: project:location:instance=tcp:3306
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a few things are being confused here, the account **used** to deploy the service vs. the account that the service is **deployed with**. These are two different things.

The account logged into gcloud and **used to deploy** your app engine service (i.e. the account with the permissions to run `gcloud app deploy`) does not have to be the same as the one that has the permissions to connect to Cloud SQL.

However, service account that is **deployed with** and used by App Engine (app engine default service account or custom service account) will and should be the same service account to authenticate to your Cloud SQL instance .

You can scope down the permissions used by App Engine by providing a custom service account over using the App Engine Default service account to only those that are required by your application. That way you can grant the `Cloud SQL Client` and `Cloud SQL Instance User` roles on top of it and not have the broad `Editor` permissions.

For more details see: [Connect Cloud SQL from App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-flexible#java_1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is exactly what I'm asking for — how to define the service account that is deployed with the app? The maven has an option to either define 'cloudSdkHome' (which is a way to define deployer account) and/or GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable which also defines deployer account but also defines the 'deployed with account'.